# Appium server sends cache values to the mobile

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I send the values via `sendKeys("csvel93@gmail.com")` only from Client. Also the values reach to `Appium server` as "csvel93@gmail.com".

But the `Appium server` send the values to the mobile as " 5172 8208 0000 9997csvel93@gmail.com".

Here " 5172 8208 0000 9997" - existing field value.

I used `Appium v1.10.0` (.exe format)

Appium Logs:

```
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"7"}}
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/8ffe1a35-ccbd-4e1d-b581-513499f72c21/element/7/value
[HTTP] {"id":"7","text":"csvel93@gmail.com","value":["c","s","v","e","l","9","3","@","g","m","a","i","l",".","c","o","m"]}
[W3C (8ffe1a35)] Calling AppiumDriver.setValue() with args: [["c","s","v","e","l","9","3","@","g","m","a","i","l",".","c","o","m"],"7","8ffe1a35-ccbd-4e1d-b581-513499f72c21"]
[AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:setText","params":{"elementId":"7","text":"csvel93@gmail.com","replace":false}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:setText","params":{"elementId":"7","text":"csvel93@gmail.com","replace":false}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: setText
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using element passed in: 7
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Attempting to clear using UiObject.clearText().
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Sending plain text to element: 5172 8208 0000 9997csvel93@gmail.com
[AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[W3C (8ffe1a35)] Responding to client with driver.setValue() result: true
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/8ffe1a35-ccbd-4e1d-b581-513499f72c21/element/7/value 200 6268 ms - 14
[HTTP]
```

Comment: Clear the field before sending the text, like `element.clear()`

Comment: can you share the code snippet

Answer (score 2):

First you need to clear existing text using the following command:

```
mobileElement.clear();
```

And then you can send new values as follows:

```
mobileElement.sendKeys("csvel93@gmail.com");
```

This is a known issue with hint fields. You can refer [Appium 1.2.2 : Android :: clearText is not working](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/3543)

Comment: Somehow log says _mobileElement.clear()_ was automatically invoked as in **`UiObject.clearText()`**